# How to Manage Email Groups in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am using Lambda + SES to send a daily email to a list of users. I am generating the list of verified emails by using the boto3 api `client.list_verified_email_addresses()` command.

However, I need to send another email to a subset of verified emails. What is the best way to create and maintain this email group?

I would perfer to maintain the group in AWS and have the Lambda code reference the AWS service. I have thought of subscribing users to an SNS topic and getting the list from the topic, or a list of emails stored in S3. Are there any better solutions or best practices I should be aware of?

Comment: Are you actually requiring each person on the list to verify their email through SES? It sounds like you are using SES in sandbox mode, which is far from ideal. It also sounds like you are trying to use SES like a mass email service similar to Mailchimp, but SES is really a lower-level service that you would use to build something like Mailchimp.

Comment: @MarkB Currently it is being used to send a report generated from a database to company internal users, so formatting the email is pretty light. We are still using sandbox mode because the emails are internal.. but need a way to group internal recipients

Comment: regardless of email formatting, I think you are still trying to use SES for more than it was designed to do. And you are definitely at the point now with grouping recipients that you are needing a higher-level abstraction on top of your email server than what SES provides. You might look into standing up a Sendy server https://sendy.co/ if you want things like email groups on top of SES without having to reinvent it all yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way would be to create an RDS database and model your email groups there in whichever way suits your use case, then pull the emails from the DB. You could use DynamoDB in a pinch as well.

A minimal (relational) DB structure for this would be something like:

```
Table: EmailRecipient
Columns:
    - emailAddress
    - name

Table: MailingList
Columns:
    - listId
    - listName

Table: MailingListEmailRecipient
Columns:
    - listId
    - emailAddress
```

The 'MailingListEmailRecipient' table functions as a many-to-many mapping between mailing lists and recipients, and you have the flexibility to add as many lists as you want, and the tables can be extended to include other relevant info, you could add a table to keep track of email blasts sent, etc.

If you wanted to use DynamoDB, that could work too; it is a bit more limiting in terms of data modelling and you could run into some issues later on, but as a quick and dirty solution it could work, and the cost might be significantly lower if the data is small and infrequently accessed. On DynamoDB you would do something like:

```
Table: EmailRecipient
Partition Key: mailingListName
Sort Key: emailAddress
Optional fields:
    - recipientName
```

This would allow you to store the recipients for a mailing list under the mailing list partition key. You could also do it the other way around (emailAddress as the partition key) which would be more optimal for DynamoDB (avoids 'hot' partitions), but if you are using DynamoDB for this then you are probably building something quick and dirty (the better way would be a RDBMS) anyway.